# A modification of a theorem on the concept of elementary family in Folland’s real analysis book

Tags: real-analysis

In *Real Analysis* by Folland, an elementary family $\mathscr E$ on a set $X$ is defined to be a collection of subsets of $X$ such that it containes the empty set, it is closed under finite intersection, and the complement of any $S\in \mathscr E$ is a disjoint union of sets in $\mathscr E$.

Folland proves that the collection $\mathscr A$ of finite disjoint unions of sets in $\mathscr E$ forms an algebra, but his proof indeed works even if we assume that $\mathscr A$ is just the collection of finite union of, not necessarily disjoint, sets in $\mathscr E$. Am I correct? If so, why does he assume the extra condition of disjointness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection of finite unions and finite disjoint unions of sets from $\mathcal E$ turn out to the same. He could have defined $\mathcal A$ without the disjointness condition.

Comment: So I was correct, thanks